# STM32 SPI enable sequence

Tags: c, stm32, spi, bare-metal

I'm trying to configure the SPI peripheral on my Nucleo-f303K8 board without using the HAL drivers as a little learning exercise. I've enabled the spi clk in the RCC register and alternate mode for the gpios so that should be okay. I've followed the steps in the reference manual but when I set the enable bit in the control register 1 the master/slave bit is reset along with the enable but the baud rate and data size settings remain. Can anyone spot any steps I'm missing in the code below?

```
//setup SPI peripheral
*spi_ctrl_1 |= (0x01 << 2);             //spi master mode set
*spi_ctrl_1 |= (0x03 << 3);             //spi speed set to fpclk/16
*spi_ctrl_2 |= (0x08 << 8);             //8 bit spi data size

*spi_ctrl_1 |= (0x01 << 6);             //enable spi
```

Comment: Use CMSIS definitions magic numbers and your (very likely wrong) hardware definitions.  CMSIS is a set of typedefs and definitions provided by STM. Doesa not have anythiong in common with HAL

Comment: Most likely not the solution to the described SPI configuration issue, but to set the SPI data size to 8-bit on an STM32F303K8, `SPIx_CR2[11:8]` needs to be set to 0b0111, which is **7** not 8, see [Reference Manual (RM0316)](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0316-stm32f303xbcde-stm32f303x68-stm32f328x8-stm32f358xc-stm32f398xe-advanced-armbased-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) section *30.9.2 SPI control register 2 (SPIx_CR2)*.

Comment: Also make sure to initialize the register to a known state, the bitwise OR assignment operator `|=` only sets bits, never clears any. Bits from its previous state might still be present (also check the reset value). A form like this is recommended to initialize a memory mapped register: `REG = (A | B...)`. That makes sure that the whole register gets initialized at once. - Most likely not the solution to the actual SPI configuration problem, please post more detailed information and if possible a [reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: no reason to assume you are not able to read a manual and get the address to a peripheral correct.  CMSIS adds a whole layer of uncertainty and risk, no need for that here.